# Strange linq exception on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework, xamarin

I have a very old project which was written with Xamarin (now Visual Studio for Mac).

This project works with a mysql database and entityframework.

When i try to do a very basic query

```
using (myentities db = myentities())
{
    customer.where(c => ... any filter ...)
}
```

I get this exception:

```
System.MethodAccessException
Method `System.Data.DataView.get_RowPredicate()' is inaccessible from method `System.Data.LinqDataView.get_RowFilter()'
```

Please note 
  - I have no exception it the table is empty.
  - It worked perfectly 2 years ago on the same computer !

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a build or runtime error?

Comment: No it is a runtime error. I got a 500 http error with this exception

Comment: Did you have upgrade the .net platform or mixin incompatible packages?

Comment: I have upgraded everything : the packages and the .net framework version (latest)

Comment: Mono has been upgraded recently with only mobile/Blazor apps in mind, so if you are working on an ASP.NET 4.x project on Mono, such can be expected. ASP.NET 4.x projects should go to Visual Studio for Windows. Or you migrate them to ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

[`LinqDataView`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/LinqDataView.cs) is using [`DataView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=netframework-4.8) (by inheritance and using [`RowPredicate` of `DataView`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/LinqDataView.cs,90))

It looks like the `LinqDataView` and `DataView` are incompatible versions, so LinqDataView is calling a DataView that when it was compiled, had RowPredicate, but the DataView in the DLL you're using hasn't a (accessible) RowPredicate

`LinqDataView` is in the System.Data.DataSetExtensions dll and `DataView` is in the System.Data dll.

So there is an incompability between System.Data.DataSetExtensions dll and System.Data dll.

Double check of those dlls/packages are updated/installed correctly. (maybe also clear obj/bin folders and check .configs for versions)